# How to pass a delegate to a delegate that expects a managed function pointer in managed C++

Tags: c++-cli

I have the following call:

```
ExecutionContext::Run(item->Context, gcnew ContextCallback(item, &WaitQueueItem::Callback), item->State);
```

where `WaitQueueItem` is the following:

```
ref class WaitQueueItem
{
public:
    WaitQueueItem(){}

    WaitCallback^ Callback;
    Object^ State;
    ExecutionContext^ Context;
};
```

`WaitCallback` is defined as `public delegate void WaitCallback(Object^ state)` in the `System::Threading` namespace.

Compilation renders the following error:

> error C2843:
>   'Foo::Bar::Data::ContainingClass::WaitQueueItem::Callback' : cannot
>   take the address of a non-static data member or method of a managed
>   type

If I provide a function with the same signature as the `WaitCallback` delegate it will compile. Digging in with dotPeek, I see that the same code when written in C#

```
ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, new ContextCallback(item.Callback), item.State);
```

looks like this:

```
ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, new ContextCallback(item.Callback.Invoke), item.State);
```

Is there a way to pass the delegate without having to write a wrapper function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must pass the address of a method in the delegate constructor, not of a delegate.  You've got a mismatch in delegate types, ContextCallback vs WaitCallback.  Silly problem since they have the same signature.  If you don't want to declare the Callback member as type ContextCallback then you need a small helper method that simply calls the Callback delegate.

Comment: That is what I have done but I was hoping for a "better" solution given the matching signatures. Given the same signature I may just do the following: `code`item->Callback = reinterpret_cast<ContextCallback^>(callback);

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```
gcnew ContextCallback(item->Callback, &WaitCallback::Invoke)
```

(which is equivalent to what the C# compiler did, binding the object instance `item->Callback` and its `Invoke` method)